# Storing subprocess.call() return value in a variable

Tags: python, subprocess

Im trying to get the number of lines in the output of `ls -l | awk '{print $1}'`, which is 7 as shown below.

```
total
drwxrwxr-x
drwxrwxr-x
-rw-rw-r--
-rw-rw-r--
-rw-rw-r--
-rw-r--r--
```

I tried to store this value in the variable `count` but when I print count, the value is 0 instead of 7. I don't know why.

```
import subprocess

count = subprocess.call('ls -l | awk '{print $1}' | wc -l', shell=True)
print count
```

OUTPUT:

```
7
0
```

Comment: Why not using `os.listdir`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a return value using subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041141/get-a-return-value-using-subprocess)

Comment: `subprocess.call()` does not return the stdout of the process called, but the returncode. In this case this is `0` (no error occured)

Comment: is there anyway to store the actual answer instead of the return value? because Im using pipes and using subprocess.calls() is easier that way

Comment: You don't want the return code here (it's 0 because the shell command exited without an error); rather, you want the standard output of the subprocess.  [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) should do what you want.

Comment: @Adonis Im trying to learn how to count lines from the shell, not necessarily only the directories, hence `subprocess.call()`

Comment: @wildwilhelm is there a way to use pipes with `subprocess.check_output` ?

Comment: The function signature for check_output is the same as for run or call or the others.  You can do shell=True, and you can redirect stderr to stdout.  Anything more complicated than that, and you can look to explicitly construct a Popen instance, as @toheedNiaz has suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the help @wildwilhelm . I tried toheedNiaz's answer, it gives ['7\n'] which is great but Mufeed's answer makes string manipulation easier for me, give 7 directly. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use subprocess.check_ouput as well. It was specifically meant for checking output as the name suggests.

```
count = subprocess.check_output("ls -l | awk '{print $1}' | wc -l", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Subprocess.call does not return stdout so you need to use Popen instead.
Here is what you can do .

```
import subprocess

count = subprocess.Popen("ls -l | awk '{print $1}' | wc -l",stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
print(count.stdout.readlines())
```