# Delete existing file after successful write

Tags: python, pg-dumpall

I am performing a daily database dump in a python script and I am looking for the most python efficient way to delete the current file only after the recent one was written successfully, i.e. delete the backup-12-11-2019.sql only after backup-13-11-2019 was created successfully

Comment: How are you writing the backup file? Can you attach some code?

Comment: try:
        pg_dumpall('-h', DB_HOST, '-U', DB_USERNAME, '-p', DB_PORT, 
        _out=BACKUP_FOLDER + 'backup-' + str(now.day) + '-' + str(now.month) + '-' 
        + str(now.year) +'.sql')
    except Exception as e: print(e)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `try:...except:...esle:` as the following code.

```
import datetime
import os
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
try:
    pg_dumpall('-h', DB_HOST, '-U', DB_USERNAME, '-p', DB_PORT, _out=BACKUP_FOLDER + 'backup-' + str(now.day) + '-' + str(now.month) + '-' + str(now.year) + '.sql')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
else:
    previous_day = now - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    os.remove(BACKUP_FOLDER + 'backup-' + str(now.day - 1) + '-' + str(now.month) + '-' + str(now.year) + '.sql')
```

If the `pg_dumpall` does not raise and `Exception` it will delete the previous backup file

Best regard

Answer (score 0):

From [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31021/how-do-i-solve-an-error-code-127-when-doing-a-pg-dumpall-through-a-cronjob)

```sh
    pg_dumpall -U pg_user > /tmp/tmp.txt
    DUMP_STATUS=$?
    echo "Dump status: $DUMP_STATUS" > /tmp/status.txt
```

And [SO: Get return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041141/get-a-return-value-using-subprocess)

```py
    subprocess.check_output([SCRIPT, "-d", date], shell=True).
```

We're able to come up with something that will run the command you want to run, and check its return value at the same time.

```py
    output = subprocess.check_output(['pg_dumpall', '-h', DB_HOST, '-U', DB_USERNAME, '-p', DB_PORT], stdout=outfile)
    if output == 0:
        print("Success")
        os.remove(oldfile)
    else:
        print("Failure")
```