# How to use last executed command's return code in python shell script

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

Dollar question mark ($?) is used to find the return value of the last executed command and I want to use it in my script but it does not work.

python version : 3.7
Library : subprocess

I searched the answer but I can't find the suit answer in python.

**I tried the following code, but it doesn't work :**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["ls","-l"])
if $? == 0 :
    print("is ok\n")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a return value using subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041141/get-a-return-value-using-subprocess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) will return the code and you can store it inside variable:

```
import subprocess
rv = subprocess.call(["ls","-l"])  # <-- result of the call is stored inside `rv` variable
if rv == 0 :                       # <-- check the variable
  print("is ok")                   # <-- no need to put additional '\n' to print statement
```

Prints:

```
... the result of `ls -l`
is ok
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`call` returns an object with a `returncode` attribute you can check.

```
result = subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
if result.returncode == 0:
    print("is ok")
```